# Return transposed list of all strings in a row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google Sheet, the range B2:2 contains mostly empty cells, but some cells contain strings. I would like to print these strings into a transposed list beginning at A12. This list should exclude all empty cells and should print (in consecutive cells) all the strings in B2:2.

So far, I've tried `=ArrayFormula(INDEX($B$2:$E$2, 0, SMALL(IF(NOT(ISEMPTY($B$2:$E$2)), COLUMN($B$2:$E$2)), ROW(1:1))` as various websites and Stack Exchange answers have suggested, and `=ArrayFormula(INDEX($B$2:$E$2, 0, SMALL(IF($B$2:$E$2<>"", COLUMN($B$2:$E$2)), ROW(1:1))`. However, these formulas have only simply transposed the entire range beginning at A12 when the B2 is filled. When B2 is not filled, no values appear.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, a combination of filter (which filters out the empty cells, keeping only the non-blank cells) and transpose, should work:

```
=transpose(filter(B2:2, len(B2:2)))
```